# Read flatgeobuf (.fgb) in R

Tags: r, gis

How can I read a flatgeobuf file in R? The only function I can find is `leafem::addFgb` but I can't find a way to access the underlying data.

```
library(leaflet)
library(leafem)

temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://esa-worldcover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/esa_worldcover_grid_composites.fgb",temp)

leaflet() %>%
  setView(0, 0, zoom = 2) %>%
  addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldTopoMap') %>%
  addFgb(file = temp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDAL handles FlatGeobuf files, so like with most other geospatial vector formats, you can load it with `{sf}`:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
st_layers("esa_worldcover_grid_composites.fgb")
#> Driver: FlatGeobuf 
#> Available layers:
#>                       layer_name geometry_type features fields crs_name
#> 1 worldcover_composites_grid_aws       Polygon    19363      9   WGS 84
read_sf("esa_worldcover_grid_composites.fgb")$geometry |> plot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks - I had tried using `{sf}` but now I realise it wasn't working because GDAL is out-of-date